# URLRewrite rule for a URL that only contains one value after the question mark

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm working on redirecting a bunch of URLs to a new schema, basically from:

```
http://www.gamikaze.tv/?XHh-1Z56av0
```

to:

```
http://www.gamikaze.tv/#!/videos:XHh-1Z56av0
```

I tried to find examples of that, but all queries examples I've seen are using a key/value pair, and this only contains one value. Also, the URL doesn't fundamentaly changed - both URLs are using index.php. How could that be achieved using an .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /#!/videos:%1? [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not quite working but it's getting there! The URL is redirected to http://www.gamikaze.tv/#!/videos: